# add multiple headers to http response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in flutter , i started to call an api from rapid api for soccer results , it's required to add many headers to call this api , when i put these headers , i had an error in syntax
here what i have tried , nothing worked

```
getResults() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/2',
        headers: ({'x-rapidapi-key': 'e8ece1dbcdmshd1d6f778c1397c5p113b22jsn8361690f93a2'},
        {'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'},
        {'useQueryString': true}));
```

I am trying to find the right syntax to make these headers works with my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

class RapidAPI {
  static const _base = 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2';
  static const _apiKey = 'e8ece1dbcdmshd1d6f778c1397c5p113b22jsn8361690f93a2';

  static Future<void> fetchFixturesLeague2() async {
    final url = '$_base/fixtures/league/2';

    print('Start fetching...');
    await HttpReqService.getJson<Map<String, dynamic>>(url, headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': _apiKey,
    })
      .then((response) {
        if (response != null) {
          print('${response['api']['fixtures'].length} items');
        }
      })
      .whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done.'));
  }
}


void main(List<String> args) async {
  await RapidAPI.fetchFixturesLeague2();
  print('Job done!');
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...
380 items
Fetching done.
Job done!
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a single map:

```
headers: (
{'x-rapidapi-key': 'e8ece1dbcdmshd1d6f778c1397c5p113b22jsn8361690f93a2',
'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
'useQueryString': true}
)
```